# Calculate maximun value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the maximun value that the function f(x, y, z) = $ x^2 +y^2 + 2z^4$ reaches in the sphere  $x^2 +y^2+z^2 = 1$

Comment: Wording is confusing; it should be either ON the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ or IN the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1$ (or better in the ball).

Comment: Well what about studying $h(z)=2z^4+1-z^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)=1+z^{2}(2z^{2}-1)$. It is easy to see that $f(x,y,z) \leq 2$ using the fact that $-1 \leq z \leq 1$. Also the value $f(x,y,z)=2$ is attained when $x=0,y=0$ and $z=1$. Hence the maximum value is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) works very well for your problem.

Try the examples on the wikipedia page with $f$ as the function you want to maximize and $g=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ as your constraint.